# How can I move the caret to sbt shell without using the mouse?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

IntelliJ IDEA 2017.x and 2018.x + Scala includes [sbt shell](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2017/07/19/intellij-idea-scala-plugin-2017-2-sbt-1-0-improved-sbt-shell-play-2-6-and-better-implicits-management/) support.

On Windows and Linux it is possible to launch sbt shell with
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. sbt shell is launched in its own tool window.

[image: sbt shell Tool Window]

My problem is that the text cursor doesn't automatically move to the shell tool window. I have to click on the panel in order to type a sbt command. This is a pretty tedious / error prone / repetitive task.

I would like to move my caret to the bottom of the sbt shell tool window without using the mouse. Basically, I would like for the sbt shell tool window to behave just like the terminal tool window (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>).

Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible and it's sort of my fault. I made an issue for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13585